# Inequality bounded by infinite sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Suppose that the goal is to prove $f(x) \leq 0$ and I construct an infinite sequence $a_n(x) > 0$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n(x) =0$.

If I can prove $f(x) \leq a_n(x)$ by induction, can I arrive at the conclusion that $f(x) \leq 0$?

For example, let $a_n(x) = \frac{1}{2^n}x$, is this true that $\forall n\in \mathbb N, f(x) \leq a_n(x) \Rightarrow f(x) \leq 0$?

Comment: Hello, if $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n(x) = 0$ doesn't it implies that you can choose any $x$, and for example set it to be $2^n$, and therefore the limit of the $n$th term equals to $1$?

Comment: You are correct. Fix $x$, and then remove the dependence on it to see it more clearly: if $f(x) \leq a_n$ where the sequence goes to 0, then clearly $f(x) \leq 0$.